# Send variable to view in request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm working on my first complex test, and I need some help.
I need to create a user, sign him in, and fill a form as him. The page raises an error: `undefined method first_name for nil:nilClass`

Both functions are pretty easy, here is the test:

```
it "simulates creator onboard" do
@user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
puts @user.onboard_token.size
visit onboard_path(:token => @user.onboard_token)
puts @user.nil?
expect(@user.active).to eq(false)
click_on('step-forward')
find('input[name="user[password"]').set "12345678"
find('input[name="user[password_confirmation"]').set "12346578"
find('input[name="commit"]').click
expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
expect(@user.active).to eq(true)
```

end

And here is the controller function:

```
 def onboard
authorize(:user, :onboard?)
if params[:token].present?
  if params[:token] != nil && params[:token].size == 40 && !User.where(onboard_token: params[:token]).empty?
     @user = User.find_by_onboard_token(params[:token])
  end
  if !@user.nil?
    sign_in(:user, @user)
    @brand = @user.profile
    sign_out(:user)
  end
else
  sign_out(:user)
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

end

For some reason, it appears that the `@user` variable is not passed to the view. I made sure it is not nil, made sure to use the correct capybara functions, but still, @user is nil in view.

Did I miss something ?

Comment: Did you try debugging it? Make sure your  `params[:token] != nil && params[:token].size == 40 && !User.where(onboard_token: params[:token]).empty?` evaluates to true and @user gets assigned to begin with, let me know if that is not the problem

Comment: One issue is that the `@user` variable in your test needs to be reloaded with `@user.reload` in order to see the changes done to the database by your application. `@vars` are instance variables - not globals - and even if they are your test and the application under test often run in different threads.

Comment: Appart from that it is kind of a mess. If you can tell us in plain terms ("When the user clicks X - Y should happen") what your controller action is supposed to accomplish we can help you more.

Comment: @max Yes, sorry, it's kinda messy. Every user in my app got a secret token, called onboard_token this token is used to register the user, he gets it in a link, token is destroyed after registration is complete.

I want to test the whole process:
User is retrieved with the token. He gets on the registration confirmation page, cliks on the "Start registration" button to bring up the form, fills it, and submit it. If everything goes right, user is now registered, and active.

Comment: @IKA Yes, I checked it all, process goes into the "if" condition

Comment: max's feedback above regarding @user.reload is correct.  You may even wish to do your assertions on User.find(@user.id) to be clear about the state transition in your DB.

Comment: What driver are you using with Capybara?

Comment: selenium. After lot and lot of testing, it appears that the `user` created by FactoryGirl is not saved, and therefore `!User.where(onboard_token: params[:token]).empty?` returns false, so @user doesn't exit.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the devise confirmable module as an example of how to implement this. You don't have to really dig through the code but spin up a simple rails app and dump devise and checkout the routes generated and how the controllers work.

Comment: Its not really that complex - and they did a nice job of modeling confirmations as a restful resource.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Selenium with Capybara this test has a number of issues

1. Objects created in the test thread aren't visible in the app thread if you're using transactional testing - https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#transactions-and-database-setup
2. Actions in Capybara are asynchronous so trying to test values on an object immediately after triggering the action (without some kind of expecation on displayed content to make sure the action has completed) is going to be flaky
3. You can't use `visit` and 'response' at the same time
4. An object that is `present?` can't be nil
5. If there is a token but no user matches it your code with still attempt to render the view but with no @user and no @brand

To solve these you need to set up something like [DatabaseCleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example) and make sure you're using truncation or deletion strategy for tests using the selenium driver.  That will allow objects created in the test thread to be visible in the app (in your case the user). Then your test should be something more like

```
it "simulates creator onboard" do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  visit onboard_path(:token => @user.onboard_token)
  #You need to expect for something that should be on the screen before checking user.active - since this can occur before the visit has actually done anything
  #expect(@user.reload.active).to eq(false)
  click_on('step-forward')
  find('input[name="user[password"]').set "12345678"
  find('input[name="user[password_confirmation"]').set "12346578"
  find('input[name="commit"]').click
  expect(page).to have_current_path(root_path)
  expect(@user.reload.active).to eq(true)
end
```

with a controller more like

```
def onboard
  authorize(:user, :onboard?)
  if params[:token].present? && params[:token].size == 40
    @user = User.find_by_onboard_token(params[:token])
    if !@user.nil?
     sign_in(:user, @user)
     @brand = @user.profile
     sign_out(:user)
    else
     # do something here because it means the token was invalid
    end
  else
    sign_out(:user)
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```